# Javascript - map value to keys (reverse object mapping)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to reverse the mapping of an object (which might have duplicate values). Example:

```
const city2country = {
    'Amsterdam': 'Netherlands',
    'Rotterdam': 'Netherlands',
    'Paris': 'France'
};
```

`reverseMapping(city2country)` Should output:

```
{
    'Netherlands': ['Amsterdam', 'Rotterdam'],
    'France': ['Paris']
}
```

I've come up with the following, naive solution:

```
const reverseMapping = (obj) => {
    const reversed = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        reversed[obj[key]] = reversed[obj[key]] || [];
        reversed[obj[key]].push(key);
    });
    return reversed;
};
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a neater, shorter way, preferably prototyped so I could simply do:

```
const country2cities = city2country.reverse();
```

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing built in that does this. Your code looks fine.

Comment: `preferably prototyped` - you don't want to add to Object.prototype

Comment: Maybe use lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/#invertBy

Comment: @SayanPal OP already achieved something. Recommending another library is irrelevant in this case

Comment: @SagarV OP is looking for a one-liner. The only way to get that is with a library, since there's nothing built-in that does it.

Comment: I'd prefer readability of code over a "neater, shorter way", so your code is OK. You could even make it a bit more readable with `var objKey=obj[key];` inside the forEach. You have a working code, don't waste your time trying to golf it (unless that is your actual goal).

Comment: @JaromandaX - why is it a bad idea to extend Object with such a method?

Comment: Popular opinion. Search SO. It's been discussed ad nauseam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), while respecting the given array of the inserted values.

```js
const city2country = { Amsterdam: 'Netherlands', Rotterdam: 'Netherlands', Paris: 'France' };
const reverseMapping = o => Object.keys(o).reduce((r, k) =>
        Object.assign(r, { [o[k]]: (r[o[k]] || []).concat(k) }), {})

console.log(reverseMapping(city2country));
```

Comment: Thanks! this is definitely closest to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such built-in function in JavaScript. Your code *looks* fine, but given that there are so many edge cases here that could wrong, I'd suggesting using [**`invertBy`** from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#invertBy), which does exactly what you describe.

## Example

> ```
> var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1 };
>
> _.invertBy(object);
> // => { '1': ['a', 'c'], '2': ['b'] }
> ```

Comment: Did someone really downvote this answer because it requires a 3rd-party library? It's the only answer that really satisfies what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, we currently don't use lodash and it seems a bit of an overkill to add for such a small method. Don't understand the downvote either.

Comment: @Daniel lodash is modular, which means you can only install this single function and use it. Not much different in terms of size than copy/paste a function from here, but much better for maintenance. Just my two cents.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović actually looks like [lodash code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/invertBy.js) is pretty similar to mine except for hasOwnProperty defense, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce to save the declaration line [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Abusing `&&` to check if the `map[object[key]]` is defined first before using `Array.concat`.

It's shorter, but is it simpler? Probably not, but a bit of fun ;)

```
const reverseMapping = (object) => 
    Object.keys(object).reduce((map, key) => {
        map[object[key]] = map[object[key]] && map[object[key]].concat(key) || [key]
     return map;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Why do you need to prevent duplicates? Object keys are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Hmm, turns out, I was mistaken. I must have used `concat(x, y)` rather than `concat(x)`.  Updating my code, as I would prefer not to use Set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get raid of duplicates first :

```
function removeDuplicates(arr, key) {
   if (!(arr instanceof Array) || key && typeof key !== 'string') {
    return false;
   }

  if (key && typeof key === 'string') {
    return arr.filter((obj, index, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[key]).indexOf(obj[key]) === index;
    });

  } else {
    return arr.filter(function(item, index, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(item) == index;
    });
  }
}
```

and then use this to make it reverse :

```
function reverseMapping(obj){
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in obj){
  ret[obj[key]] = key;
  }
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: `reverseMapping(city2country)` just maps the country to one city, not an array of cities. How do you use your answer to get his desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting an array of values and an array of keys from the current object, and setup a new object to hold the result. Then, as you loop through the array of values -

- if the object already has this value as the key, like `Netherlands`, you create a new array, fetch the already existing value (ex: `Rotterdam`), and add this and the new value (`Amsterdam`) to the array, and set up this array as the new value for the `Netherlands` key.
- if the current value doesn't exist in the object, set it up as a new string, ex: `France` is the key and `Paris` is the value.

Code -

```js
const city2country = {
    'Amsterdam': 'Netherlands',
    'Rotterdam': 'Netherlands',
    'Paris': 'France',
};

function reverseMapping(obj) {
  let values = Object.values(obj);
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  let result = {}
  values.forEach((value, index) => {
    if(!result.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
      // create new entry
      result[value] = keys[index];
    }
    else {
      // duplicate property, create array
      let temp = [];
      // get first value
      temp.push(result[value]);
      // add second value
      temp.push(keys[index]);
      // set value 
      result[value] = temp;
    }
  });
  
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

reverseMapping(city2country)
```

The benefit here is - it adjusts to the structure of your current object - `Netherlands` being the repeated values, gets an array as it's value in the new object, while `France` gets a string value `Paris` as it's property. Of course, it should be very easy to change this.

Note - [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) might not be supported across older browsers.

Comment: He's looking for something simpler than his existing code. Your function is 3x longer.

Answer (score 0):

@Nina Scholz answer works well for this exact question. :thumbsup:

But **if you don't need to keep both values** for the Netherlands key (`"Netherlands": ["Amsterdam", "Rotterdam"]`), then this is a little bit shorter and simpler to read:

```
const city2country = { Amsterdam: 'Netherlands', Rotterdam: 'Netherlands', Paris: 'France' };

console.log(
  Object.entries(city2country).reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item[1]] = item[0]) && obj, {})
);
// outputs `{Netherlands: "Rotterdam", France: "Paris"}`
```

Comment: Actually you broke her code. You lost the value "*Amsterdam*".... check the SO's question again; and Nina's answer code output.

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay attention to that part! I will just keep the answer here but give more details to specify the case when it's a correct usage. It could help someone in a slightly different case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by some of the other answers, here is a short reusable function:

```js
/**
 * Take an object with key->value mapping and return
 * an object with the inverse value->keys[] mapping.
 */
function invertObj(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
      result[value] = (result[value] || []).concat(key);
      return result;
    }, {});
}
```

Usage with the example from the question:

```js
invertObj({
    'Amsterdam': 'Netherlands',
    'Rotterdam': 'Netherlands',
    'Paris': 'France'
});
// => {
//   "Netherlands": [ "Amsterdam", "Rotterdam" ],
//   "France": [ "Paris" ],
// }
```